# Parsing Strings with ANTLR4

Tags: antlr, antlr4

I am trying to parse strings with the following structure:

> Client: Heli Maintenance Ltd, Site: Head Office, Device: ORDERS-W10

And want to extract the ClientName, SiteName and DeviceName.

I have defined the following grammar.

```
grammar AuditIdentifier;

row: 'Client:' customer ',' 'Site:' site ',' 'Device:' device '\r'? '\n';

customer : TEXT | STRING  ; 
site : TEXT | STRING  ;

device : TEXT | STRING  ;

TEXT: ([a-zA-Z0-9]|' ')+  ;   
STRING: '"' (ESC|.)*? '"' ; 
fragment ESC: '\\"' | '\\\\' ; // 2-char sequences \" and \\ 
WS  :   [ \t\n\r]+ ->
skip ; COMMA: (',')->skip;
```

However it does not seem to run as expected. It only recognizes the customer tag.
This is my grunt output when I try to run with the example text. 
Client: Heli Maintenance Ltd, Site: Head Office, Device: ORDERS-W10

The grunt tool also outputs these errors:
Client: Heli Maintenance Ltd, Site: Head Office, Device: ORDERS-W10
line 1:34 token recognition error at: ':'
line 1:55 token recognition error at: ':'
line 1:63 token recognition error at: '-'
line 1:29 missing 'Site:' at ' Site'

line 1:48 missing 'Device:' at ' Device'

Comment: you have the customer tag defined before the site and device tag. Because they all have the same defintions, customer will override the tags for site and device.

Comment: switching it does  not do anything.